# Not able to import Facebook SDK into Eclipse

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Greetings of the Day.. I downloaded latest Facebook SDK from [This Official Link](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-current.zip)

Now I extracts that ZIP file and there is a folder named as facebook. When I am selecting  import and then from Existing and locating This facebook path them I am not able to do it. Please help me . How can I import this library ?

Comment: Are you using Maven project?

Comment: No sir its my Android project and I am importing this into Eclipse

Comment: Does it give you any error?

Comment: Actually when You import library then select OK button in Eclipse.. But in my Case when I am location facebook library path, its not accepting that path.

Comment: You may have a project with the same name already in your eclipse workspace.

Comment: No there is no any project is related with Facebook

Comment: Eclipse telling you why it is not accepting the path?

Comment: No, I am not able to see error

Comment: I am getting such error 


Select a directory to search for existing Android projects

Comment: HI Thnxx to all of you for your support. I get acknowledgement from stack that Latest Face book SDK which contains .aar file is basically developed fro Android Studio , and it wont be support to Eclipse .